# How to fetch mysql data when I click side bar menu link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sidebar menu with links "approved users, pending users, and rejected users".

I need to implement this:  when I click on approved users link in sidebar, the approved_users.php page should load with all users who are approved.

Similarly, I want to load pending users and need to approve or reject them using update query.

```html
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['approved'])){ ?>


<table>
    <thead>
            
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 AND role != 'admin' ";
$resul = $db->query($query);
$num_row = $resul->num_rows;
if($num_row == 0){
    echo "<tr><td class='info'>No record found.</td></tr>";
}else{


$count = 0;
while($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()){

$id = $row['id'];
$fullname = $row['fullname'];
$username = $row['username'];
$email = $row['email'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$password = $row['password'];
$address = $row['address'];
$role = $row['row'];
$count++;

 ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $count ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fullname ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $phone ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $email ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $username ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $password ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $address ?></td>
    <td><span><?php echo $role ?></span></td>
</tr>


   <?php

} // end of while

} // else end

        } // Approved - if 
}
        ?>

</table>
```

Comment: what's the problem with current code ?

Comment: I am interested in knowing where are you using this code for? Is it a school project, hobby project, production code? PHP has really evolved and such kind of code is really frowned upon. You can evaluate if using something like knockout js will be an appropriate solution for your problem.

Comment: as suggested by @Ravi your code looks fine. There can be run-time problems like SQL query failing or the GET not having the appropriate value. You need to add some debug logs and see what is happening.

Comment: Code is right... but I want to implement it on button (menu link) I want to know how to implement this on button.

Comment: I used <a href="approved_users.php">Approved Users</a>
and then added that code into approved_users.php but no data show even there are records in the database.

Comment: One more thing,
I used the code for pending users and it display the data but when I use the code for approved users & rejected users pages, it doesn't load any data.
What I'm doing wrong?????

Comment: @JayRajput it's a college project. There is no error but data is also not displaying even "no record found" is also not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The tbody tag is missing which is causing the problem. Please add the tbody tag.